# what is correct format for list param in hql

Tags: grails, hql

```
RaceRegistration.executeQuery("select RaceRegistration.compositeEvent.id FROM RaceRegistration where RaceRegistration.id in :registrationIds group by RaceRegistration.compositeEvent.id",
                     [registrationIds: [1,2]])
```

In the above query my doubt is in the last part [registrationIds: [1,2]]. Here i am assuming that the format for the list is wrong. I appreciate any help in correcting the format. Thanks!

I get the following exception

```
Exception thrown

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: Unable to resolve path [RaceRegistration.compositeEvent], unexpected token [RaceRegistration] [select RaceRegistration.compositeEvent.id FROM com.runnercard.registration.RaceRegistration where RaceRegistration.id in :registrationIds group by RaceRegistration.compositeEvent.id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [RaceRegistration.compositeEvent], unexpected token [RaceRegistration] [select RaceRegistration.compositeEvent.id FROM com.runnercard.registration.RaceRegistration where RaceRegistration.id in :registrationIds group by RaceRegistration.compositeEvent.id]

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:656)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeFind(HibernateTemplate.java:343)

    at com.runnercard.registration.RaceRegistration.executeQuery(RaceRegistration.groovy)

    at com.runnercard.registration.RaceRegistration$executeQuery.call(Unknown Source)

    at ConsoleScript5.run(ConsoleScript5:4)

Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [RaceRegistration.compositeEvent], unexpected token [RaceRegistration] [select RaceRegistration.compositeEvent.id FROM com.runnercard.registration.RaceRegistration where RaceRegistration.id in :registrationIds group by RaceRegistration.compositeEvent.id]

    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.resolveAsNakedComponentPropertyRefLHS(IdentNode.java:219)

    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.resolve(IdentNode.java:108)

    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolveFirstChild(DotNode.java:175)

    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:576)

    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1181)

    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRefLhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5495)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says something else. It seems you have a problem with the mapping on the *RaceRegistration* class. It seems that the field *compositeEvent* is not mapped or is not mapped correctly.

So actually your question is wrong considering the exception thrown.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work RaceRegistration.executeQuery("select E.compositeEvent.id FROM RaceRegistration E where E.id in :registrationIds group by E.compositeEvent.id", [registrationIds: [1L,2L, 3L]] )